# How can I switch back to Hotmail from Outlook.com

Tags: outlook.com

My Hotmail has been switched to Outlook.com automatically and I do not like the Outlook at all. I just need to get my Hotmail back and tried to do the steps mentioned. I can't find the sentence on how to switch back to the old Hotmail?

Comment: What steps mentioned where?

Comment: Going forward is always scary, but when an email service is deprecated, it is for good reason. Having a "new" email provider also makes you appear more up-to-date with technology. This is especially helpful if you are submitting résumés.

Answer (score 17):

I am sorry to say *you cannot*. Since Outlook.com has left "preview" the migration from Hotmail is permanent.

> [Microsoft's Hotmail phase-out: What's a user to do?](http://www.zdnet.com/microsofts-hotmail-phase-out-whats-a-user-to-do-7000011688/)
>
> Q: If I move my Hotmail account to an Outlook.com account, can I change my mind and go back?
>
> A: At this point, no. (When Outlook.com was still in "preview," Microsoft did allow this.)

Also (from **Microsoft Support**):

> [Why can't I switch back to Hotmail?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/outlook/switch-back-hotmail)
>
> Thanks for being a loyal Hotmail customer. As part of the transition from Hotmail to Outlook.com—the next generation of free email from Microsoft—there is no longer an option to switch back.