# How do I log in to Hotmail instead of Outlook.com?

Tags: outlook.com

I have been trying to log in to my Hotmail account and I can't because Outlook.com keeps coming up instead. Is there any way that I can still log in to Hotmail?

Answer (score 1):

Hotmail as a service was discontinued some time ago. If you had an active Hotmail account, you should now be able to use Outlook.com to access your email.

If the account was not used for some time, it's possible that Microsoft has shut it down.

See also: [How can I switch back to Hotmail from Outlook.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/41628/how-can-i-switch-back-to-hotmail-from-outlook-com)